# Create an SSL connection with ODBC driver to MySQL(5.6) using openSSL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, odbc, ssl

I want to create an asymmetric SSL connection from MySQL to an ODBC driver but don't fully know how to generate the keys and certificates (I'm using openSSL as recommended here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html ).

I've been following this post to try and create the keys

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244129/use-rsa-private-key-to-generate-public-key

It seems like the key generation works but I don't know where or how the keys are stored to use them with the ODBC driver.

Also it may be helpful to know that I am generating these keys on the server host machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL / MariaDB SSL Connection without verify CA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185617/mysql-mariadb-ssl-connection-without-verify-ca)